# Given a series of numbers in table(c1), find the missing numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Given a series of numbers in table(c1), find the missing numbers. The numbers should be consecutive

```
c1
--
1
2
3
6
7
8
9
12
14

Expected output:
i
-
4
5
10
11
13
```

Comment: Interview question? Homework? LEFT join the table to a generated sequence and look for nulls

Answer (score 3):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select s.i
from (select generate_series(min(c1), max(c2), 1) as i
      from t
     ) s left join
     t
     on s.i = t.c1
where t.c1 is null;
```